# Best practice C++: Reuse default arguments for multiple methods

Tags: c++, coding-style, default-value

Given a header file that has different functions (function1 and function2): what is the best practice of sharing the same default arguments?

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        virtual ... function1(..., int param1 = 48, int param2 = getStuff(99)) = 0;
        virtual ... function2(..., int param1 = 48, int param2 = getStuff(99)) = 0;
}
```

Using something like

```
#define PARAM1 = 48
#define PARAM2 = getStuff(99)
```

seems rather inconvenient. I am fairly new to C++ so I don't know whats the best practice in this case. Should I instead create some private constant inside of MyClass?

Comment: Using member variables instead of parameter?

Comment: I see nothing wrong on using the defines. Provided you give the defines a meaningfull name. e.g. NUMBER_OF_SECONDS_IN_A_DAY.

Comment: regarding member vars: that seems like a reasonable approach, however, I also have default arguments that are set by some function from which I do not want to store the return values but which I want to call every time the function is called.

Comment: In C++, use `const` variables instead of `#define`.

Comment: Using const instead of #define would be "best practice" for c++ but otherwise you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void function1(int param1 = default_param1, int param2 = default_param2());
    void function2(int param1 = default_param1, int param2 = default_param2());

private:
    static const int default_param1 = 48;
    static int default_param2() { return getStuff(99); } // assuming it might change
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your functions are virtual - be aware that the default parameters are not inherited!

```cpp
int getStuff(int n)
{
    return n;
}

class MyClass
{
public:
    static constexpr int DefaultParam1 = 48;
    static constexpr int DefaultParam2 = 99;

    virtual ~MyClass() = default;

    virtual void function1(int param1 = DefaultParam1, int param2 = DefaultParam2) = 0;

    inline void function2()
    {
        function1(getStuff(DefaultParam1), getStuff(DefaultParam2));
    }
    inline void function2(int param1)
    {
        function1(param1, getStuff(DefaultParam2));
    }
    virtual void function2(int param1, int param2) = 0;
};
```

Have a look at function2 in my example, it is overloaded with inline functions. Advantage:

```cpp
class MC : public MyClass
{
public:
    virtual void function1(int param1, int param2)
    {
    }
    using MyClass::function2;
    virtual void function2(int param1, int param2)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    MC mc;
    ((MyClass&)mc).function1();
    mc.function2();
    return 0;
}
```

`function1` requires a cast to be used with default parameters (without repeating them in the inheriting class), `function2` does not (unfortunately, you need the using clause to make the overloads visible in the inheriting class, though).

Side note: I'm not telling the first approach is wrong or bad, I'm just showing an alternative...